# Python AWS Lambda Execution New Update

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Update

I changed the params to receive the data directly from a JSON dump to see if that fixed the JSON load issue.  Received a new error:

> (b'{\n  "errorType": "ValidationMetadataException",\n
> "errorMessage": "The a'  b'rgument is null or empty. Provide an
> argument that is not null or empty, and'  b' then try the command
> again.",\n  "stackTrace": [\n    "at Amazon.Lambda.P'
> b'owerShellHost.PowerShellFunctionHost.ExecuteFunction(Stream
> inputStream, ILa'  b'mbdaContext context)",\n    "at
> lambda_method1(Closure , Stream , ILambda'  b'Context , Stream )",\n
> "at Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport.Bootstrap.User'
> b'CodeLoader.Invoke(Stream lambdaData, ILambdaContext lambdaContext,
> Stream ou'  b'tStream) in
> /src/Repo/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport/Bootstrap/U'
> b'serCodeLoader.cs:line 145",\n    "at
> Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport.Handler'
> b'Wrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.b__0(InvocationRequest
> invoc'  b'ation) in
> /src/Repo/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport/Bootstrap/Han'
> b'dlerWrapper.cs:line 56",\n    "at
> Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport.LambdaBoot'
> b'strap.InvokeOnceAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in
> /src/Repo/Libr'
> b'aries/src/Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport/Bootstrap/LambdaBootstrap.cs:line
> 176'  b'"\n  ]\n}\n')

Still having no success with passing in the lambda name.  The code has been updated from the previous post.

==============================================================
ORIGINAL POST

I am trying to execute a lambda function through python.  I can successfully do it when I hardcode the variables but when I substitute the variables in I am unable to process the lambda.

Here is the working sample with hardcoded values:

```
params = {"value1": "value1-value", "value2": "value2-value", "value3": "value3-value"}
client = boto3.client('lambda')
response = client.invoke(
    FunctionName='MyLambdaFunctionName',
    InvocationType='RequestResponse',
    Payload=json.dumps(params).encode(),
)
pprint.pp(response['Payload'].read())
```

The part that fails is when I replace params with variables. The plan is to pass them in, as I call values but right now, I am testing it and setting the values in the function.  The variables are listed below:

**json_data** |
**lambdaName** |

```
lambdaName = os.getenv('TF_VAR_lambdaName')
value1="value1-value"
value2="value2-value"
value3="value3-value"

data = {"value1": "value1-value", "value2": "value2-value", "value3": "value3-value"}

params = json.dumps(data)
client = boto3.client('lambda')
response = client.invoke(
    FunctionName=lambdaName,
    InvocationType='RequestResponse',
    Payload=json.dumps(params).encode(),
)
pprint.pp(response['Payload'].read())
```

The error I get goes away when I hard-code the JSON or the Lambda Function Name.

The error log I am getting is listed below:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/go/src/github.com/repo/./cleanup/cleanup.py", line 25, in
> <module>
>     response = client.invoke(   File "/Users/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/botocore/client.py",
> line 515, in _api_call
>     return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)   File "/Users/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/botocore/client.py",
> line 893, in _make_api_call
>     request_dict = self._convert_to_request_dict(   File "/Users/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/botocore/client.py",
> line 964, in _convert_to_request_dict
>     request_dict = self._serializer.serialize_to_request(   File "/Users/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/botocore/validate.py",
> line 381, in serialize_to_request
>     raise ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report()) botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
> Invalid type for parameter FunctionName, value: None, type: <class
> 'NoneType'>, valid types: <class 'str'>
```

Comment: Clearly `TF_VAR_lambdaName` does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you have is in the definition of your lambda:

```
lambdaName = os.getenv('TF_VAR_lambdaName')
```

Try following:

```
LAMBDA_NAME = os.environ.get('YOUR_LAMBDA_NAME') // make sure you put the exact name of your lambda in ''
```

Than use it in your code:

```
response = client.invoke(
  FunctionName=LAMBDA_NAME,
  InvocationType='RequestResponse',
  Payload=json.dumps(params).encode()
)
```

Comment: I get the same error with your recommendation.  Doesn't like the lambda name

Answer (score 0):

The community, thanks for your support here.  I finally figured it out with the help of my colleague.

## So the first issue:

> lambdaName = os.getenv('TF_VAR_lambdaName')

This was odd that it wasn't working since i had already exported the environment variables using

> export TF_VAR_lambdaName="myfunctionname"

I ended up using a print statement to check the value, and it came out with none.  Googling it a bit, found a post where someone suggested rerunning the export to set the value again and that did the trick.  I did take a bit from Olgas suggestion and modified the export as follows:

> LAMBDA_NAME = os.getenv('TF_VAR_lambdaName')

just making the variable all caps to avoid any issues.

## Second Issue:

This one turned out to be an easy fix.  The short in sweet of it is I didn't need

> **json.dumps(data)**

The declaration of data was already being passed in a format that **params** needed.  What worked was just setting *params equal to* **data** and lambda was able to handle it.  Final working code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import boto3
import json
import pprint
import os    

LAMBDA_NAME = os.getenv('TF_VAR_lambdaName')
    value1="value1-value"
    value2="value2-value"
    value3="value3-value"
    
    data = {"value1": value1, "value2": value2 "value3": value3}
    
    params = data
    client = boto3.client('lambda')
    response = client.invoke(
        FunctionName=LAMBDA_NAME,
        InvocationType='RequestResponse',
        Payload=json.dumps(params).encode(),
    )
    pprint.pp(response['Payload'].read())
```